# Is it a good practice to use Microsoft power bi for visualizations of a retail data warehouse

Tags: ssis, powerbi, ssrs-2008, ssas, data-warehouse

I completed my ETL part in SSIS. Now for data visualization i installed Power BI for dashboards and reports. Also i read research papers and I didn't find anyone related to power Bi. Lastly, Do i need to implement SSAS and SSRS package as well.

Comment: "Also i read research papers no one use power BI" Please reference it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power BI's strength is data visualisation, and it is likely to be well suited for for using on top of you retail data warehouse.

I'm not sure which research paper you are referring to, but Microsoft has been topping Gartner's Magic Quadrant for Analytics and Business Intelligence Platform for several years now, followed by Tableau and Qlik.  If you are interested in reading further around the various platforms, you can download from https://info.microsoft.com/ww-Landing-2021-Gartner-MQ-for-Analytics-and-Business-Intelligence-Power-BI.html?LCID=EN-US

Power BI does not require SSAS or SSRS to run.  If you already have SSAS, Power BI can use SSAS as a data source, and it works very well with a live connection, alternatively you can model the semantic layer directly within Power BI itself.  Power BI, especially now Paginated reports are included is seen as a cloud based alternative to SQL Server Reporting Server